how to filter datetime by day in django with timezone utc aware?
The datetime objects I am trying to filter are 2024-10-26 00:49:34.131805 in the database, which is 9pm in my country. what happens is that when I am trying to filter by day (created_at__day=timezone.now().day) it returns day 26, which is ok, but Django translates them to the correct timezone (9pm the previous day) when filtering and ends up mismatching values.
What I need to do?
settings.py
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Sao_Paulo'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True

models.py
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

query
day = timezone.now().day
filter = Model.objects.filter(created_at__day=day)

this is what i tried
date = timezone.now()
filter = Model.objects.filter(created_at__date=date)

and that worked...
but i really wanted to filter just by day. Does Django provide something or am I doing something wrong?

You may can filter by range and set the start and end time of the day:
from datetime import timedelta
from django.utils import timezone

now = timezone.localtime(timezone.now())

start = now.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
end = start_of_day + timedelta(days=1)

result = Model.objects.filter(
    created_at__gte=start,
    created_at__lt=end,
)

Pay attention to not use filter as variable, because that is a built in Python function.

it worked, thank you. but why did my first attempt to filter DateTimeField with a random DateTimeField of the day work? doesnt it have to be the exact hour, minutes and seconds?

When USE_TZ is True, filtering by day (created_at__day) will operate in UTC by default, and this can lead to mismatches if you are filtering for local days rather than UTC days.

thats not what i meant tho. i thought filtering DateTimeField (date + time) would only work when you passed the exact date and time, but that doesnt seem to be the case since it works using timezone.now()

The reason it worked is because you extracted the date part of the datetime. You did this: created_at__date, which when returning a non-null value is equivalent to datetime_object.date()
